# Update the entity after approval from administrator

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, jpa

I do have an entity and it has a status enum, PENDING and APPROVED. Whenever the user wants to create this Entity it needs to be approved by the administrator then it changes the status and it's visible in other endpoints. I would like to add possibility to update some fields of that entity but do not persist them until this will be approved. For example when we have an Entity with name A and it was approved it should be visible with name A, but when I would like to update it's name to be B, then this should be still visible with name A until it will be approved, then it should have the name B. Do you have any ideas how to implement this kind of approach? Do I need a separate database table or something?

Comment: It depends if you want your entity to be updated in memory only, and such once the application restarts, you will lose such (PENDING changes), or if you want those (PENDING changes) to be persisted...then you would probably need an intermediate table

Comment: @SMA I would like to persist it.

Comment: I think two separate databases are the most safe option. One for PENDING and one that is actually used in production. This PENDING status clearly means that the entity does not belong in the production environment, so do not put it there to avoid confusion.

Comment: @k-wasilewski There is only one database, so there can be two tables I believe.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're asking for this solution:

```
@Transient
private String myNewField;
```

Fields annotated so will be ignored by JPA.

Comment: I do not, I would like to have all fields persisted, when it's approved then this will be visible to other users as the status will be switched from pending to approved, but I would like to add possibility to update this Entity without modifying the approved one until the modified will be approved, then those fields should be updated, so I believe that an abstract entity is needed and two entities for two different tables.